# class variable doesn't update after __call__

Tags: python, class, call

I have probably an easy question. Why if I run `get_predictions` method inside `print` it gives me `[]` and not a `[1,2,3]`? Value assignment should be done at object creation (`__call__`).

```
class Learner():
    def __init__(self):
        self.predictions = []

    def get_predictions(self):
        return self.predictions
    
    def __call__(self):
        self.predictions = [1,2,3]
        

l = Learner()

print(l.get_predictions())
```

Comment: You never call the instance. You meant to write: `l()` just before the `print(...`.

Comment: If you want something to happen at object creation, that's `__init__`, not `__call__`.

Comment: Sorry for so nooby question

Comment: This does not seem like a good use-case for `__call__`.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks. I assumed the `__call__` would return `self`

Comment: @JonSG: Yes, that's what I thought. Unfortunately there seems to be *no* methods which `return self` by default.